# No instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Optional<U> conforms to Response

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have the following:

```
Optional<Resource> updatedResource = update(resourceID, data);

if (updatedResource.isPresent()) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(updatedResource.get()).build();
}
```

I would like to avoid the `isPresent` and `get` calls if possible, so I tried

```
return update(resourceID, data).map(updatedResource -> Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(updatedResource).build();
```

but IntelliJ shows me the following error:

`No instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Optional<U> conforms to Response`

Why do I get this error, and is there a way to avoid it and also avoid `isPresent` and `get`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the error, the return type of your method is `Response`. However, `update(resourceID, data).map(updatedResource -> Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(updatedResource).build())` returns an `Optional<U>`, so you have to change the return type to `Optional<Response>`.

So the method would look like this:

```
public Optional<Response> yourMethod (...) {
    return update(resourceID, data).map(updatedResource -> Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(updatedResource).build());
}
```

Or, if you don't want to change the return type, add an `orElse` call, to specify a default value:

```
public Response yourMethod (...) {
    return update(resourceID, data).map(updatedResource -> Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(updatedResource).build()).orElse(defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: @JornVernee You'd need `flatMap` if the mapper function (`Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(updatedResource).build()` in this example) returns an Optional. I assumed this wasn't the case, based on the error message.

Comment: Oh, I misread the first part of your answer as the mapping function doing just that. My bad

Comment: Nice one, thanks, very helpful. I see that using `orElseThrow` also works.